# Must Declare Scalar Value?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, scalar

I am working with SQL and c# for my assignment. For this assignment I am running a movie database and I am stuck on this part where I have to check out a movie. I keep getting a 'must declare scalar value' but I am unsure how to do that.
My code:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="panel5" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:GridView id="one_data" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" DataKeyNames="MovieID">
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="MovieTitle"
                    HeaderText="Movie"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateChecked"
                    HeaderText="Date Checked"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CheckedOut"
                    HeaderText="Checked Out"/>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Choose another Movie" OnClick="GoBack" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Check Out" OnClick="CheckOut" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

Panel 5 gets a selected movie that the user chooses and when they hit the check out button the fields 'DateChecked' and 'CheckedOut' are supposed to be filled with the date and a 'Y' for yes.
CS Code:

```
public void CheckOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        get_connection();
        try
        {

            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Content SET DateChecked=@DateChecked, CheckedOut=@CheckedOut WHERE MovieID=@MovieID", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateChecked", DateTime.Now);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckedOut", 'Y');

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            one_data.DataSource = reader;
            one_data.DataBind();



            reader.Close();
        }
```

I left out the catch part because it's unimportant. When I hit the checkout movie button I keep getting the error and if I remove the WHERE clause, it works except that all movies are updated instead of the one I chose. What would be the fix for this?

Comment: You're not adding a SQL parameter for the `@MovieID` value

Comment: @Igor `ExecuteNonQuery` makes more sense.  `ExecuteScalar` is really meant for a query that you expect to get one row and one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UPDATE command has three values, which are defined using @

You have specified two of them, but you didn't specify the @MovieID

```
command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Content SET DateChecked=@DateChecked, CheckedOut=@CheckedOut WHERE MovieID=@MovieID", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateChecked", DateTime.Now);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckedOut", 'Y');
```

As a result it won't be able to form some valid SQL. You need to add the movie ID

`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieID", movieId);`

Presumably you'll get this from your boundfield for movie title.

Comment: How would I get the the movieid from the boundfield?

Comment: There are several steps you need to understand here, basically you need to use the RowCommand event to get the specific row, if you have one button per row, instead of OnClick, then in your RowCommand you can access all the values in the gridview row and retrieve the ones relevant to you.